# How to remove unknown session that already been started without your knowledge

Tags: php, mysql, session

How can I remove a unknown session start without my knowledge?

I get this notice:

> Notice: a session had already been started -ignoring session_start

[Screenshot of the errormessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9AMa.jpg)

Comment: Does that file include any files? Where do you start the session? `session_start()` should always be called *before* any output is made, as with PHP headers.

Answer (score 0):

The `session_start()`- function can only be called one time, and is then defined for the rest of the file. If you have it included from another file, you need not call it again from this file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could check with `session_status()` if session is already running and then decide whether or not to call `session_start()`

Have a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php